# python string format for variable tuple lengths

Tags: python, printing, string-formatting

I have a tuple of numbers let's say nums = (1, 2, 3).  The length of nums is not constant.  Is there a way of using string formatting in python to do something like this

```
>>>print '%3d' % nums
```

that will produce

```
>>>   1   2   3
```

Hope it's not a repeat question, but I can't find it if it is.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
print ('%3d'*len(nums)) % tuple(nums)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody's said it yet:

```
''.join('%3d' % num for num in nums)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use .join():

```
nums = (1, 2, 3)
"\t".join(str(x) for x in nums) # Joins each num together with a tab.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ''.format

```
nums = (1, 2, 3)
print(''.join('{:3d} '.format(x) for x in nums))
```

producing

```
>>>  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this enough for you?

```
print ' '.join(str(x) for x in nums)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
params = '%d'
for i in range(1,15):
    try:
        newnum = (params)%nums
    except:
        params = params + ',%d'
        next
    print newnum
```

Comment: Have you even tried to run this? Hint: it will crash if the size of `nums` is larger than 1.

Comment: When looking at it now, I see how you're thinking. However, there must be an indentation error on the last line. The way the code is written here, it will crash if `len(nums) > 1`, and if `len(nums) == 1`, it will print the number 14 times.